# How to get web3py transaction complete

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, web3py

Where is a mistake?

```
while True:
        balance = w3.eth.get_balance(pubadd)
        gasPrice = w3.to_wei('55', 'gwei')
        gasLimit = 2000000
        nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(pubadd)
        tx = {
            'nonce': nonce,
            'to': add,
            'value': balance-gasLimit*gasPrice,
            'gas': gasLimit,    
            'gasPrice': gasPrice
        }
        try:
            signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, privkey)
            tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

I feel like I have to do something with price and limit but nothing helps

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 'value': balance-gasLimit*gasPrice 
the problem is here seems like I messed up with wei or count or something. cause if I use constant all goes through

Answer (score 0):

You can get the transaction complete by:

```py
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_confirmation(tx_hash)
assert tx_receipt["status"] == 1, "Transaction was not successful"
```

See [wait_for_confirmation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/web3.eth.html?highlight=wait_for_confirmation#web3.eth.Eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt) documentation.